# Why won't Internet Explorer 9 beta load?

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I'm using Windows 7 on an ASUS machine. I have updated my Internet Explorer from 8 to 9 beta. Now I cannot open it. I'm double-clicking, but no IE window opens. What do I have to do to use Internet Explorer?

Comment: Make sure it is not already running under task manager (right click task bar and select "start task manager" and make sure that iexplore.exe does not appear there) If it does, select it and the press the end process button, and try again. If you want to uninstall it and try again you can go to control panel and click "view installed updates" in the left hand column and find internet explorer 9 in the list that appears. Good luck!

Comment: @Jay - Your comment is good enough to be an answer. I would have given it a +1.

Comment: Beta versions of IE are not that easy to uninstall. They should only be installed on virtual machines or where Windows can be reinstalled.